# Determine primary postgresql node with prisma

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I'm using `prisma` in my `NextJS` application. And I have a `PotgreSQL` cluster with 3 nodes, each one in a different URL.

Normally the node 1 is the primary, and the other two are `read-only`. But sometimes, this changes, so now the node 2 is the primary and the one is `read-only`.

Having this configuration:

```js
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("DATABASE_URL_N2")
}
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction
```

This is because my `DATABASE_URL` now is not the primary node, but is a `read-only`.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance